# Spring Data R2DBC with JPA annotations

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc

I'm using JPA annotation in order to annotate my entities:

```java
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "GITTBQDCF")
@org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table(name = "GITTBQDCF")
public class QdCF {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "QDCF_ID")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "QDCF_CODI")
    private Long codi;
```

My repository:

```java
public interface QdCFRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<QdCF, Long> {}
```

All above annotations are ignored. I mean, generated queries are fetching data from `qd_cf` instead of `GITTBQDCF`.

It seems that `spring data r2dbc` is ignoring JPA annotations.

I need spring data scans for JPA annotations.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and solved it by using @Table from org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping. So you should remove jakarta's @Table annotation and use only spring's instead. I hope I helped someone...